# How to load an audio with fs.readFileSync () code

Tags: javascript, python, audio

I'm having trouble loading an audio with fs.readFileSync (), I'm trying to send an audio to whatsapp using javascript, but when the code sends the audio I can't open it.
I tried to change the audio extension to mp3, ogg, and wav, but they all gave the same problem.

Code JavaScript:

```
  const fs = require("fs");
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

  // code to run the code speech.py in python

  const process = spawn("python", ["./speech.py", text]);
  process.stdout.on('data', data => {
     console.log(data.toString());
  });

  if (text.length > 200){
     conn.sendMessage(id, "Mensagem muito longa", MessageType.text);
  }else{

  // function to send message audio with delay
  setTimeout(function(){
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync("./mp3/som.ogg")
  conn.sendMessage(id, buffer, MessageType.audio)

  // function to delete audio message inside the mp3 folder
  setTimeout(function(){
  const process2 = spawn("python", ["./delete.py"]);
  process2.stdout.on('data', data => {
     console.log(data.toString());
  });}, 
  4000);}, 
  5000);
```

Code Python: (Create the audio file)

```
import gtts
import sys

msg = sys.argv[1]
msg = msg.replace("!tts ", "")

obj = gtts.gTTS(text = msg, lang = "pt-br", slow = False)
obj.save("./mp3/som.ogg")
```

Code Python: (Delete the audio file)

```
import os

fileTest = "./mp3/som.ogg"

try:
    os.remove(fileTest)
except OSError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("File is deleted successfully")
```